# Display:inline-block is not running properly

Tags: html, css, block, display

I want to arrange three pink boxes in 1 row.
However, applying display:inline-block creates a space on top.
What's the problem?

---------------HTML----------------

```
<div class="hello">
  <h1>이건 첫째</h1>
</div>
<div class="hello">
  <h2>이건 둘째</h2>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="helloCss">
  <h2>이건 셋째</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Css</li>
    <li>World!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="helloJava">
  <h2>이건 넷째</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>World!</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

---------------SCSS----------------

```
$g:rgb(115, 115, 115);


@mixin box($color:pink){
    color:$g;
    background-color:$color;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid $g;
}

.hello{
    display:inline-block;
    input{
        margin:{
            left:10px;
            top:10px;
        }
    }
    @include box();
    h1{
        background-color:rgb(238, 206, 219);
    }
    &Java{
        @include box();
        background-color:rgb(175, 202, 255);
    }
}

.helloCss{
    @extend .hello;
}
```

[image]

margin 0, padding 0, wrap in one div, change h1 and h2 to span
Even if I raise the mouse from the developer tool, the area does not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the  elements are classed as `inline` the browser vertically aligns the text baseline to adjacent elements by default. If you draw a line under the bottom row of text you'll see they're all positioned next to each other.

More info from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

[image]

The easiest way to fix this is the add `vertical-align: top` or similar to your css as follows:

```css
.hello,
.helloCss {
  display: inline-block;
  
  vertical-align: top; /* added this */
  
  color: #737373;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #737373;
}

.hello input,
.helloCss input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hello h1,
.helloCss h1 {
  background-color: #eecedb;
}

.helloJava {
  color: #737373;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid #737373;
  background-color: #afcaff;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
  <h1>이건 첫째</h1>
</div>
<div class="hello">
  <h2>이건 둘째</h2>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="helloCss">
  <h2>이건 셋째</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Css</li>
    <li>World!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="helloJava">
  <h2>이건 넷째</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>World!</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh!!!!!! It works!!! The boxes are sorted by the end of the text! Thank you Soooo much!! :)

Comment: My pleasure @DoeunChoi. Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

As Timothy mentioned, it could be the default behavior of inline-block. However, if making a slight change to your HTML is an option, creating a parent div with flex is much easier for aligning divs.

*html*

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>이건 첫째</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="hello">
    <h2>이건 둘째</h2>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="helloCss">
    <h2>이건 셋째</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
      <li>Css</li>
      <li>World!</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="helloJava">
  <h2>이건 넷째</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>World!</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

*CSCC*

```
$g: rgb(115, 115, 115);

@mixin box($color: pink) {
  color: $g;
  background-color: $color;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid $g;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}
.hello {
  input {
    margin: {
      left: 10px;
      top: 10px;
    }
  }
  @include box();
  h1 {
    background-color: rgb(238, 206, 219);
  }
  &Java {
    @include box();
    background-color: rgb(175, 202, 255);
  }
}

.helloCss {
  @extend .hello;
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank you So Much!!! Why did you give 5px to gap??

Comment: You are very welcome! I saw that you had white spaces between pink boxes, and adding a gap creates white spaces for the aligned divs :)